# SSH ~/.ssh/.config file doesn't work

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to connect to a remote server through SSH, but I want to make an alias of the server name, and connect using a username different from my default one

Basically, I must enter the command :

```
ssh remoteUsername@host
```

But I want to access it using

```
ssh customHostname
```

I appended this to my `~/.ssh/.config` file, but it doesn't work :

```
Host customHostname
  HostName host
  User remoteUsername
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I've checked that the usernames are the same, and i tried rebooting the PC, but it still doesn't work

Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content looks fine so far but the config file usually is `~/.ssh/config` as described [here](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/config).

Comment: General FYI: it's better to link to the actual man page, as there's no efficient means to verify the third-party site redundant explanations are current and up-to-date. OpenSSH [`ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) manpage